# KOMA warning about ToC

Tags: table-of-contents, koma-script, warnings

Lately I've noticed the following warning from KOMA when I compile my documents:

```
Class scrreprt Warning: \float@addtolists detected!
(scrreprt)              You should use the features of package `tocbasic'
(scrreprt)              instead of \float@addtolists.
(scrreprt)              Support for \float@addtolists may be removed from
(scrreprt)              `scrreprt' soon .
```

The documentation for KOMA makes a brief mention of package `\tocbasic` but none of the examples there mention anything about `\float@addtolists`, unless this information is in the German documentation and hasn't been translated to English yet.

What does the warning mean, and can anyone suggest what changes I can make to silence it?

Comment: If you are using the »[float](http://ctan.org/pkg/float)« package to create new floats, replace it by the mentioned »tocbasic« package which is part of the [KOMA-Script](http://ctan.org/pkg/koma-script) bundle. Its relevant features are described in Section 11.2.3 of the English user guide.

Comment: See also: `texdoc scrhack`

Answer (score 41):

KOMA uses his own algorithm to create float environments provided by `tocbasic`.

So packages like float or listings uses an old version and produce this warning. However Markus Kohm wrote a small package named `scrhack` fixing this issue.

*Example 1 without `scrhack`:*

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
\lstlistoflistings 


\begin{lstlisting}[caption={example}]
 for i=1 by 1 to 10 do
   i++
 od:
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Warning:

```
Class scrartcl Warning: Usage of deprecated \float@listhead!
(scrartcl)              You should use the features of package `tocbasic'
(scrartcl)              instead of \float@listhead.
(scrartcl)              Definition of \float@listhead my be removed from
(scrartcl)              `scrartcl' soon, so it should not be used  on input lin
e 5.
```

*Example 2 with `scrhack`*

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{scrhack}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
\lstlistoflistings 


\begin{lstlisting}[caption={example}]
 for i=1 by 1 to 10 do
   i++
 od:
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

0 warnings

Comment: Wait, so this occurs if you've got *any* floats at all in the document?

Comment: @zoqaeski: It's related ot `\listof...`

Comment: I tried adding `\usepackage{scrhack}` and `\usepackage{listings}` (though I'm not sure if I need that) and I still get that warning.

Comment: @zoqaeski: Which version do you use?

Comment: KOMA 2011/06/16 v3.09a. The other packages are here: https://gist.github.com/2619654 - maybe I've got conflicts or older versions of something else?

Comment: shouldn't you load scrhack after listings?