# KOMA and float package - alternative to float [H] placement

Tags: floats, koma-script

I am preparing a thesis template (for the blog here http://tex.blogoverflow.com/) and I use a `KOMA class` together with the `float` package. I get the nasty warning which is already described and solved in here:

[KOMA warning about ToC](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51867/koma-warning-about-toc) (`\float@addtolists detected!`)

I use the float package because of the `[H]` placement option (place the floating object right 'Here' and nowhere else).

Is there a way to achieve this without the `float` package? Maybe with the `KOMA class`?

Comment: You could just place your figure in the text without the `figure` environment; if you want to add the caption use the `\captionof` command provided by the package `caption` (also by `capt-of`).

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I still want to use the standard syntax. A template should use the "best practice".

Comment: I don't think it is considered "best practice" to place a nonfloating float, as this kind of contradicts its meaning. Pier Paolos comment is "best practice" here, as far as I would say. I may very well be wrong, though.

Comment: I see what you mean. Let's not argue about that. I just wanted to see if there is another placement option.

At my university the professors don't like when the pictures etc appear before they are mentioned in the text. And in my experience it is a common request from other LaTeX users. But please - no fight about that here.

Comment: @ManuelKuehner Why not use the scrhack package? I think it's from the author of the KOMA classes. I'm unfortunately not aware of a pure KOMA class solution.

Comment: @John: That's my current solution. Just wanted to avoid an additional relatively unknown package. But you are right.

Comment: Do you know the printed Version of the KOMA documentation? I would highly recommanded it (in german).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use one of the commands `\captionof`, `\captionaboveof` or `\captionbelowof` defined by the KOMA-Script class:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{mwe}
\begin{document}
\section{Examples}
\blindtext
\begin{center}
  \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
    \centering
    \captionaboveof{table}{First Table}
    \fbox{Table}
  \end{minipage}
\end{center}
\blindtext
\begin{center}
  \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{example-image}
    \captionof{figure}{First Image}
  \end{minipage}
\end{center}
\blindtext
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\end{document}
```

[image]

`\captionaboveof` formats the caption as a heading. So the caption is not too close to the table below. There is also an option that could be used if all table captions are headings: `captions=tableheading`. Then a caption defined by `\captionof{table}{...}` is also set with the correct space to the table below.

Comment: Thanks! Do they still appear in the list of figures and so on?

Comment: Yes they still appear there.

Comment: So far so good. How do you fix the \ref{} link to navigate to the top of the figure, instead of jumping to the caption?