# Using "float" package for option "H" but KOMA doesn't like it?

Tags: floats, koma-script

I used the `float` package for the possibility "H" in figure and table environments to have those things exactly there in the text where I want it to have and not what LaTeX thinks it will be better...:-)

Now, I want to use the report class from KOMA script but there I have this problem/message you can read there: [KOMA warning about ToC](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51867/koma-warning-about-toc)

```
Class scrreprt Warning: \float@addtolists detected!
(scrreprt)              Implementation of \float@addtolist became
(scrreprt)              deprecated in KOMA-Script v3.01 2008/11/14 and
(scrreprt)              has been replaced by several more flexible
(scrreprt)              features of package `tocbasic`.
(scrreprt)              Since Version 3.12 support for deprecated
(scrreprt)              \float@addtolist interface has been
(scrreprt)              restricted to only some of the KOMA-Script
(scrreprt)              features and been removed from others.
(scrreprt)              Loading of package `scrhack' may help to
(scrreprt)              avoid this warning, if you are using a
(scrreprt)              a package that still implements the
(scrreprt)              deprecated \float@addtolist interface .
```

How can I use this "H"-option with `listings` and normal pictures/tables in KOMA?

Wishes,
Mike

Comment: it seems, that KOMA bundle like to tell you that use of `[H]` is desperate action of the last resort ... never ever use it! If `[!ht]` doesn't positioning figure/table in desired place, means, that there is not enough room for it and that use of `[H]` will give ugly result ... (with no image on desired place) .

Comment: The easiest solution is not to use `float`. If you want a non-floating table just use `\begin{center}\captionof{table}{bla bla} ... \end{center}`. No need for the `H` option…

Comment: Do what Clemens said, it is the most convenient solution.

Comment: I have a different opinion (just an opinion -- please don't fight about it). I use the proposed solution (see below) for many years now and I am very happy with it. I do not always use the KOMA classes and when I copy and paste code from different documents then I find it convenient not to have to distinguish between KOMA classes and other classes.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner no need to use `H` in any class: the easiest definition of `\captionof` is `\providecommand\captionof[1]{\def\@captype{#1}\caption}` and `{center}` is always available. KOMA-Script's definition (and the one from the `caption` package) are more flexible but that's what `\providecommand` is for, anyway)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can **load the `scrhack` package** (from the `KOMA` author) - which makes the `float` package compatible with the `KOMA` classes. This is already mentioned in the warning message that you show in your question (saw this after writing the answer).

### From The Documentation

> Some packages from other authors may have problems with KOMA-Script.
> In my opinion some packages could be improved. [...] This means,
> scrhack redefines macros of packages from other authors!

### Packages that are hacked in `scrhack`

1. `hyperref` (, old versions of, see Readme below)
2. `float`
3. `floatrow` (never heard of it)
4. `listings`
5. `setspace`
6. `lscape`

### From the [Readme](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script) (2021/06/25 v3.34)

```
==============================================================================
scrhack - patch some isues with other packages
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Maintainer:     Markus Kohm
E-Mail:         komascript at gmx info
Abstract:       scrhack is a LaTeX package of the KOMA-Script bundle. It
                patches other packages to make them work better and adds new
                features to improve their interaction with KOMA-Script. One
                main feature is to make them work with tocbasic instead of
                KOMA-Script's deprecated float list interface. Currently,
                patches for float.sty, floatrow.sty, (old versions of)
                hyperref, listings, and setspace are available.
Requires:       scrkbase - internal KOMA-Script package with basics
                tocbasic - features for helper files and float environments
                xpatch - extending etoolbox patching commands
License:        LPPL 1.3c or later
State:          Author maintained
Version:        2021/06/25 v3.34
```

Comment: The `hyperref` hack is for very old `hyperref` versions only. If you are using a current `hyperref` release, this hack is disabled automatically.

Comment: @Schweinebacke Thanks for the additional information.