# Placing listings in page margins

Tags: listings, margins, marginpar, sidenotes

### Goal

My goal is to place listings in the margins. I want to use `sidenotes` for this, not `snotez`, because I also require other functionality present in the former, but not the latter.

---

### What I tried

I have absolutely no experience with LaTeX package development.

I tried to modify the code for the `marginfigure` from the [`sidenotes`](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/sidenotes/sidenotes.pdf) package documentation, which is

```tex
\newsavebox{\@sidenotes@marginfigurebox}
\DeclareCaptionStyle{marginfigure}{font=footnotesize}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{marginfigure} { o }
{
  \begin{lrbox}{\@sidenotes@marginfigurebox}
    \begin{minipage}{\marginparwidth}
      \captionsetup{type=figure,style=marginfigure}
}
{
    \end{minipage}%
  \end{lrbox}%
  \@sidenotes@placemarginal{#1}{\usebox{\@sidenotes@marginfigurebox}}
}
```

and I ended up with

```tex
\newsavebox{\@sidenotes@marginlistingbox}
\newenvironment{marginlisting}
{
  \begin{lrbox}{\@sidenotes@marginlistingbox}
    \begin{minipage}{\marginparwidth}
      \captionsetup{type=figure,style=marginlisting}
}
{
    \end{minipage}%
  \end{lrbox}%
  \marginpar{\usebox{\@sidenotes@marginlistingbox}}
}
```

### Result / Error message

But when using this code I get the error message

```tex
A <box> was supposed to be here.
 
‪main.tex, 39‬
<to be read again> 
                   s
l.39 \begin{marginlisting}
                          
I was expecting to see \hbox or \vbox or \copy or \box or
something like that. So you might find something missing in
your output. But keep trying; you can fix this later.
```

as well as this result:

[image]

The listing has the correct width, but it is not placed correctly (like the figure is). Further, there is `sidenotes@marginlistingbox` placed on the page multiple times in weird locations.

---

## Question

Could anyone please kindly point out what I did wrong and help me create a working `marginlisting` environment? Any help is gladly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

---

## Complete MWE:

```tex
\documentclass[paper=a4]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

% page geometry
\usepackage[inner=2cm, outer=7cm, marginparwidth=5cm, marginparsep=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{showframe}

% content in margins
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{sidenotes}

% listings
\usepackage[newfloat]{minted}
\definecolor{bg}{RGB}{248,248,248}
\setminted{bgcolor=bg,breaklines}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\DeclareCaptionStyle{marginlisting}{font=footnotesize}

\begin{document}

\newsavebox{\@sidenotes@marginlistingbox}
\newenvironment{marginlisting}
{
  \begin{lrbox}{\@sidenotes@marginlistingbox}
    \begin{minipage}{\marginparwidth}
      \captionsetup{type=figure,style=marginlisting}
}
{
    \end{minipage}%
  \end{lrbox}%
  \marginpar{\usebox{\@sidenotes@marginlistingbox}}
}

\section{Listing}

\begin{marginlisting}
\begin{minted}{bash}
# prerequisites
sudo apt-get install python3-pygments
\end{minted}
\caption{A listing in the margin}
\end{marginlisting}

\section{Figure}
\begin{marginfigure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\marginparwidth]{example-image-a}
    \caption{A figure in the margin}
\end{marginfigure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are ok with calling a listing "Figure" in the caption then you can just use `marginfigure` for the listings.

If you want to change the caption label to *Listing* then you can define a wrapper around `\begin{marginfigure}` and `\end{marginfigure}` to change the caption. A quick way of doing this is to use `\def\marginlisting`, which automatically defines `\begin{marginlisting}`, and `\def\endmarginlisting`, which defines `\end{marginlisting}`. Using `\def` bypasses various sanity checks which allows for a simple transfer of arguments from the wrapper environment to the inner `marginfigure`.

If you want the side listings to appear in the List of Listings then you can add `type=listing` as option in the caption setup of the marginlisting environment. Note that if you use the List of Listings together with marginnote/sidenotes in a KOMA script document class then it is advised to load the package `scrhack` to address the use of `\float@listhead` (see [KOMA warning about ToC](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51867/koma-warning-about-toc)).

MWE:

```
\documentclass[paper=a4]{scrartcl}

% page geometry
\usepackage[inner=2cm, outer=7cm, marginparwidth=5cm, marginparsep=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{showframe}

% content in margins
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{sidenotes}

% listings
\usepackage{minted}
% address deprecated \float@listhead
\usepackage{scrhack}
% wrapper around marginfigure to set the caption label
\def\marginlisting{%
\captionsetup[figure]{type=listing,name=Listing}%
\marginfigure%
}
\def\endmarginlisting{\endmarginfigure}

\definecolor{bg}{RGB}{248,248,248}
\setminted{bgcolor=bg,breaklines}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\section{Listing}
\begin{marginlisting}
\begin{minted}{bash}
# prerequisites
sudo apt-get install python3-pygments
\end{minted}
\caption{A listing in the margin}
\end{marginlisting}

\section{Figure}
\begin{marginfigure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\marginparwidth]{example-image-a}
    \caption{A figure in the margin}
\end{marginfigure}
\listoffigures
\listoflistings
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, good catch... I should have put `\captionsetup{type=listing,style=marginlisting}` instead. If possible, I want to have the label say `Listing` instead of `Figure`, but I will use your workaround if that is not possible.

Comment: @ThomasFlinkow I added some code to change the caption label.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to consider the `memoir` class macro `\sidebar{<text>}` which puts its argument into the margin (starting at the top of the page). if there are several `\sidebar` on a page they are listed in the margin in order and if they are too long to fit on a page they will continue in the margin(s) of the following pages.

The following is an example (but I'm not familiar with `minted` so I have ignored that).

```
% sidebarprob.tex  SE 609190

\documentclass[article]{memoir} %% set chapters as sections
\DisemulatePackage{caption} %% ignore memoir's caption code
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{comment}

%\usepackage{minted}  %% I don't understand this package

\begin{comment}  %% comment out OP's original code

\documentclass[paper=a4]{scrartcl}

% page geometry
\usepackage[inner=2cm, outer=7cm, marginparwidth=5cm, marginparsep=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{showframe}

% content in margins
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{sidenotes}

% listings
\usepackage{minted}
% wrapper around marginfigure to set the caption label
\def\marginlisting{%
\captionsetup[figure]{name=Listing}%
\marginfigure%
}
\def\endmarginlisting{\endmarginfigure}

\definecolor{bg}{RGB}{248,248,248}
\setminted{bgcolor=bg,breaklines}

\end{comment}  %%%%%% end of commented code

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Listing}

\sidebar{
%\begin{minted}{bash}  % I can't use minted
\textit{\# prerequisites}

sudo apt-get install python3-pygments
%\end{minted}
\captionof{figure}{A listing in the margin}
}


\chapter{Figure}
\sidebar{
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\marginparwidth]{example-image-a}
    \captionof{figure}{A figure in the margin}
}

\sidebar{
\lipsum[1]
}

\end{document}
```

[image]